# infinity redirection as Dos Attack

Tags: denial-of-service, url-redirection

I was wondering that infinite redirection could be used as a dos attack

in my case, I have this
test.php

```
    <?php 
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        header('Location: '.$newURL);
    ?>
```

if I use it like http://mysite.com/test.php?url=http://mysite.com/test.php?url=http://mysite.com/test.php?url=http://mysite.com/test.php?url=...

Can that cause dos attack?

I know that the browser will block redirection after so many redirects but I talk about using a specific script to do attack?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is no Denial of Service vulnerability. Even if a single browser were to constantly request resources from your server, it would likely not go down.

A Denial-of-Service attack can have multiple reasons:

1. A vulnerability that causes the server to crash.
   For example, an attacker can cause the server to read `/dev/zero`. As the file is of infinite length, the server never stops and hangs.
2. A vulnerability that causes the server to work a lot more on a response than the client for a request. This is called an amplification attack.
3. Many many people request resources from your server, and your server doesn't have the memory and/or bandwidth to keep up. This is usually refered to as "Distributed Denial-of-Service" (DDoD).

As you see, your "redirect to self" vulnerability really doesn't fall in any of these categories, for multiple reasons:

1. Any modern, non-malicious browser will stop redirects after a certain amount, and display an error message, as answered by [Joseph](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/214576/163495).
2. Even if that were not the case, URLs can only have a limited length, so you would end up with ~100 requests, not infinite ones.
3. A malicious user could just keep holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to infinitely refresh your page and get the exact same effect. The fact that they can do this is independent of your redirect, and can be done to any server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a read of `/dev/zero` wouldn't hang the server. It would eat up as much bandwidth as it can supply to the client reading it, but that's certainly not enough to saturate its uplink.

Comment: @forest I had some badly written applications that would hang as soon as they tried to read `/dev/zero`, and the only way to get them to un-hang was to kill the process and restart it. It's just an example how a DoS can be done in other ways than exhausting ressources.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't. Even if you were to make an infinite loop, browsers will quickly give up following it, and show a message like this (this one in particular is from Firefox):

> ## The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can
>   sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: what if an attacker used custom script !!!!!!

Comment: The server voluntarily disabling it self is usually not considered a DoS.